# Dialog not obeying my position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

For some reason, JQuery dialog refuses to start at the starting point when the height is bigger than the container (or page). Anyhow, I have set up a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3Rwy/11/).

The main issue is that my dialog with 1000px height doesn't start at the top left of the anchor as specified:

```
$("#dia2").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal : true,
    height: 1000,
    width: 300,
    resizable:false,
    draggable:false
});

$("#opendia2").bind('click', function(){
    $("#dia2").dialog( "option", "position", { my: "left top", at: "left top", of: $("#anchor") } );
    $("#dia2").dialog('open');
});
```

Instead, it starts at the top of the page but does obey the left since it is not too wide for the window.

**The question:** 
Is there any way to force JQuery UI to not try to prevent scrolling and just follow the given parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the [positioning docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/), the default behavior for when a jquery element overflows the window in some direction is to `flip` it so to maximize the visibility of the element.  This is what's causing your problems.  You can turn off the default by setting `collision: "none"`.

Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z3Rwy/12/)